# Adding text as ICON in mapinfo in mapinfo buttons

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

It's a question with yes or no answer and if yes How? Is it possible to add text label as icon in mapinfo buttons.

- Instead of :

> ```
> Create buttonpad "sitestatusbutton" As
>   ToggleButton
>     ID 1011
>   Icon MI_CURSOR_FINGER_LEFT <--------------------here
>       Calling site_statusAction
>       HelpMsg siteStatus(1)
> Show
> ```

- Something like:

> ```
> Create buttonpad "sitestatusbutton" As
>   ToggleButton
>     ID 1011
>   Icon "MYICON"&lt;-------------here
>       Calling site_statusAction
>       HelpMsg siteStatus(1)
> Show</li>
> ```

Comment: Well, you create your own icons/bmps and use these as the icon on your buttons.
Would that be okay?

Comment: @peter can I make icons without making .dll file

Comment: I believe you have to make a dll to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: See Peter's comment.